# Using quarkus Panache MongoDb with a credentials provider

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have code which is reading and writing to a MongoDb database by setting the relevant user name and password properties in my application.resources file. However in our production environment I need to get these values from our AWS SSM store.

I have tried a few ways to do this but without success. Using SsmClient I can read the values but I have failed to set the properties in my code.
I have looked the credentials provider but all the examples I can find seem to refer to relational databases. Is there a recommended way to do this? Thank you.

EDIT:
I have this method

```
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getCredentials(String credentialsProviderName) {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> secretParams = ssmProvider.getParameters(List.of(dbUserName, dbPassword));
    properties.put("PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME", secretParams.get(dbPassword));
    properties.put("USER_PROPERTY_NAME", secretParams.get(dbUserName));
    log.infof("Password %s", properties.get("PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME"));
    log.infof("Username %s", properties.get("USER_PROPERTY_NAME"));
    return properties;
  }
```

Which is logging the correct values from my secrets store but when I try to connect I get the following error

```
Error creating synthetic bean [875fc6d3e776003a77cb64e6876f962a3525aded]: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "password" is null%
```

Can anyone help

EDIT2 For anyone looking do not fall into the trap I did "USER_PROPERTY_NAME" and "PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME" are not strings. Removed the qoutes and all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Support for `CredentialsProvider` with MongoDB was added in Quarkus `3.0.0.Alpha6`.

See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/31555) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much I had blindly missed the properties relating to mongodb credentials

Comment: I have made an edit. Sorry to bother you again but you might have seen the error I am getting. The hanks

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question and adding a sample project that exhibits the problematic behavior (if possible)